# php db query to display certain user data (Smarty included)

Tags: php, mysql, templates, smarty

I have managed to create a login form which GETS user data from database and displays user data, but i would now like to display the table_name to which that user is related to.

The thing is i will have to use an `JOIN` because it needs to query the data from 2 tables.

**My Problem**

I keep getting an error, im not sure if my query in my `php` file has the wrong syntax and if my method is just the wrong approach.

**Connection**

Keep in mind my database connections (`$db`) works perfectly as the user can already log in with username and password

> **Error**
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\score4score\table.php on line 42

**Database: tables**

```
table: sc_tables
+------+----------+-------------+
| t_id | user_id  | table_name  |
+------+----------+-------------+
|  1   |     1    | bobs        |
+------+----------+-------------+

table: sc_scores
+------+----------+-------------+-------+
| s_id | user_id  |    t_id     | score |
+------+----------+-------------+-------+
|  1   |     1    |      1      |  50   |
+------+----------+-------------+-------+
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
   include("config.php");
   session_start();

   $userId = (isset($_GET["user_id"]) && is_numeric($_GET["user_id"]) && (int)$_GET["user_id"] > 0) ? (int)$_GET["user_id"] : 0;

   $query = "SELECT `a`.`table_name` FROM `sc_tables` AS `a` JOIN `sc_scores` AS `b` ON `a`.`t_id` = `b`.`t_id`";

   $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);

     $rows = array();

     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     $rows[] = $row;
     }

   $smarty->assign('rows', $rows); 
   include("header.php");
   $smarty->display('records.tpl');

 ?>
```

**TPL** (records.tpl)

```
<div>
 <div>
    The current rankings table: 
    <table>

        {foreach from=$rows item="row"}
        <tr>
            <td>{$row.table_name}</td>
        </tr>
        {/foreach}

    </table>
 </div>
</div>
```

It would be much appreciated if someone can just point me in the right direction. thanks

Comment: Your database query caused an error, that’s why $result is false. So please go research what you need to do to first of all find out what this error was.

Comment: thanks, do you think it could be the syntax? or is that at-least correct?

Comment: `mysqli_query` but `mysql_fetch_array`. Do you know the difference between `mysqli` and `mysql`?

Comment: And in your tables there're no `table_id` fields.

Comment: So I even don't know how to close this))) As a typo or as mix apis.

Comment: sorry i missed the mysql(i) , Thanks for that! now my error Notice: Undefined variable: rows in.....

Comment: Thnks you @u_mulder was missing the i in mysqli_fetch_array...

Answer (score 0):

There is no `table_id` field in the tables. So, you should have:

```
$query = "SELECT `a`.`table_name` FROM `sc_tables` AS `a` JOIN `sc_scores` AS `b` ON `a`.`t_id` = `b`.`t_id`";
```

The error says that the value FALSE is passed as argument to `mysql_fetch_array($result)`. E.g. your `mysqli_query()` returns FALSE, not a `mysqli_result` object, as it should.

If problem persists after upper changes, without seeing any error, then you should use also `mysqli_errno()`, `mysqli_error()`and `mysqli_error_list()`.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks yess , sorry im was a bit quick on this one, i actually use table_id this was just an example database tables, ill edit my post. I did miss the i in  mysqli_query() now my error is Notice: Undefined variable: rows i, so ill go do morer investigation on this now.. thanks man

Comment: @Ylama No problem. I read the comments after my answer, so I'm up to date :-)

Comment: @Ylama Let me guess: you deleted the (") from arround `item="$row"` in template :-) You are welcome. Good luck.

Comment: nope that works , was missing the injection from mysqli_query() haha , rookie mistake, but its all good since i am totally rookie